# Finding dimension of the subspace of $\mathbb{P_{3}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, solution-verification

The question is that(from Bernard Kolman, Linear Algebra). Find the dimension of the subspace of $\mathbb{P_{3}}$ consisting of all vectors of the form, $at^3+bt^2+ct+d$, where $b=3a-5d$ and $c=d+4a$.

---

First I substitute the values that I have given in the question. That is:
$at^3+(3a-5d)t^2+(d+4a)t+d$=$a(t^3+3t^2+4t)+d(-5t^2+4t+1)$ and because we can write this as a linear combination I concluded that it spans, say $\mathbb{W}$ subspace of $\mathbb{P_{3}}$ and I wrote it in the form $\{t^3+3t^2+4t, -5t^2+4t+1\}$. After that I thought that it must be linearly independent(properties of being a basis). So,
$a_{1}(t^3+3t^2+4t)+a_{2}(-5t^2+4t+1)=0$ and then, I made a matrix:
$\left[
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 \\
    3 &-5 \\
    4 & 4 \\
    0 & 2 \\
  \end{matrix}
  \left|
    \,
    \begin{matrix}
      0  \\
      0  \\
      0  \\
      0  \\
    \end{matrix}
  \right.
\right] \equiv \left[
  \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 \\
  \end{matrix}
  \left|
    \,
    \begin{matrix}
      0  \\
      0  \\
      0  \\
      0  \\
    \end{matrix}
  \right.
\right]$. So one can clearly see that $a_{1}=a_{2}=0$. And finally I conclude that $\dim(\mathbb{W})=1$, but then I thought that it may $2$. So I confused. Thanks for helping me, any contribution will make me happy.

Comment: Your argument is hard to follow because you use the word "it" which seems to refer to a polynomial and suddenly it seems to refer to a set ...

Comment: I will pay attention to that for my future questions thanks for feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basis for the space is $\{t^{3}+3t^{2}+4t, -5t^{2}+t+1\}$ and the correct dimension is $2$.

Comment: I remember that $\mathbb{P_{n}}$ has $(n+1)$ dimension, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, dimension of $\mathbb P_n$ is $n+1$. Why do you need that when you have a basis for the subspace?

Comment: Because I have founded that $\mathbb{W}$ spanned by two vectors, so $n+1=2$ and $n=1$